# Chrome extension: add HTML into web page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've seen this answer:

[Chrome extension: Insert fixed div as UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979903/chrome-extension-insert-fixed-div-as-ui/17984701)

which inserts a div into the current web page.

However, it gets pretty tiresome to be doing this all the time:

```
                            "div.id = 'myDivId';" +
                            "div.style.position = 'fixed';" + 
                            "div.style.top = '50%';" +
                            "div.style.left = '50%';" +
```

Is it possible to insert a fully-formed HTML template instead (i.e. that you include as template.html in the extension)?

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods.

#### Expose resources to content script via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources)

Then the content script can load them using the URL obtained with [chrome.runtime.getURL()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL).

If your UI is complex then go with the iframe approach - its contents will be a full-fledged extension environment like a browser_action popup with its own chrome://extension URL.

The downside is that your resources may be read by any site directly and the sites may easily detect the presence of your extension.

#### Use messaging and read the resources via the background script

content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({cmd: 'getTemplate'}, html => {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
});
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (msg.cmd === 'getTemplate') {
    fetch('/templates/foo.html').then(r => r.text()).then(sendResponse);
    return true;
  }
});
```

#### Use a compiler/bundler

There are plugins for major bundlers/compilers that allow to inline the file contents in another one so you can include a HTML template in your compiled content script as a literal string.